# Q> AHK Add a Rule Disable RMouse and LMouse During MMB click and hold

Tags: autohotkey

is there a way to add this rule to this script

```
r::
send {Mbutton down}
KeyWait, r
send {Mbutton Up}
return
```

MMB is the default navigation orbit for sketchup i want to swap it to R 
and i was able to do it

now i want to add a rule that when i hold and press mmb it will automatically disable Left Mouse Button and Right Mouse Button
so that it will not activate pan or context menu

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Do you want to disable the mouse buttons on the r hotkey you defined or do you want to add that to a new mmb hotkey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$r::                            ; The $ prefix forces the keyboard hook to be used to implement this hotkey.
send {Mbutton down}
Disable_Left_Right_Button = 1   ; creates the variable "Disable_Left_Right_Button" and sets its value to 1 (= true)
KeyWait, r                      ; waits until the key is released
send {Mbutton Up}
Disable_Left_Right_Button = 0   ; sets the value of the variable to 0 (= false)
return


;define the context in which the mouse buttons should be inactive:

#If (Disable_Left_Right_Button = 1) ; Code below is only valid if the value of the variable is true. 
                                    ; That means that if it's true, the mouse buttons are not going to work.
    Lbutton::
    RButton::
     return

#If                                 ; turns off the context sensitivity
```

Comment: explanation would help